# How to redirect based on user role with PassportJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, passport.js

I need to redirect 3 types of users (based on a single user model schema). How can I do this within my router.post() call in the users route? I understand that passport.authenticate takes in certain parameters but I am wondering if there is any way around it to have multiple redirects based on the user type (role in the schema)? Many thanks!
here is how I am doing it for one type of users:

```
//////this is my passport.js file//////

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      // Match user
      User.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};



/////////auth.js file/////////
module.exports = {
  ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in to view that resource');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  },
  forwardAuthenticated: function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }      
  }
};


//////users.js route bellow/////////
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');
const { forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Login Page
router.get('/login', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('login'));

// Register Page
router.get('/register', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('register'));

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { role, name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  if (!role || !name || !email || !password || !password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
  }

  if (password != password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      role,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists' });
        res.render('register', {
          errors,
          role: role,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password2
        });
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          role,
          name,
          email,
          password
        });

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser
              .save()
              .then(user => {
                req.flash(
                  'success_msg',
                  'You are now registered and can log in'
                );
                res.redirect('/users/login');
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});




 // Login
   router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
       passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/aboutus',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
      })(req, res, next);
});



// Logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you want to achieve, but what I understand is that you want to redirect users based on their role. I guess a simple switch / case statement would do the job.

Comment: Hi Sylvain and thank you for your comment. I appreciate your understanding for the ambiguity of my question. Just to be sure, are you saying that I should wrap the router.post call within a switch / case statement? I don't think I can use it inside. Can you kindly suggest a scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that on post you can do something like this :

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.role === 'normalUser') {
        res.redirect('/normalUserPage')
    } else if (req.body.role === 'administrator') {
        res.redirect('/administratorPage');
    } else if (req.body.role === 'receptionist') {
        res.redirect('/receptionistPage');
    }
});
```

I am pretty sure that this should do, make sure that these conditions come after trying to
sign in with the email and password provided.

What you pretty much have to do is set a condition for the three users, and based on the user type you can redirect them to their specific page.

another solution is to log in with the provided information and display the same page. However, based on the users' role, you can specify the content they are viewing.

example :

if the user type is admin, expose a div that allows them to view all the data with the ability to edit or delete.

if the user is normal, expose a div that allows them to view only the content specified for them. For instance only the names without any other information.

if the user is a receptionist expose a div that allows them to view all the content but without the ability to edit any information.

I really hope this helps you. let me know if this does help you.
If it does not help you I can try to figure out another solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but for those that stumble across it...I had the same issue and this is how I addressed it:

In `users.js` route, include

```
router.get('/redirectLogin', (req, res) => {
    if(req.user.role === role){ //replace role with whatever you're checking
        res.render('dashboardOne.ejs')
    } else {
        res.render('dashboardTwo.ejs')    
    }
})
```

Then in the login POST method, change successRedirect to:

```
 // Login
   router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
       passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/users/redirectLogin',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
      })(req, res, next);
});
```

Remember that `passport.deserializeUser()` attaches the user object to req.user, which allows you to access any attributes of that object.